# Scrolllock controller, switch shortcut if else

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, service, vbscript, keyboard-shortcuts

Halo,

i want to program for cmd, powershell, VBS which working as switch for Scroll lock key. If schroll lock is off my ethernet interface is on and wlan interface is off, else scroll lock is on, ethernet is off and wlan is on. And after this program install as service to computer.

Is something like that possible and functiona?

Thnx for all answer.

Answer (score 0):

Halo all!

I solved my problem, use AutoHotKey with my progam:

```
~ScrollLock::  ; detect ScrollLock without blocking it (~)
if (GetKeyState("ScrollLock", "T"))  ; get the toggle-state of ScrollLock
    Run, "C:\Users\%username%\desktop\off.bat"
else
    Run, "C:\Users\%username%\desktop\on.bat"
```

Have a nice day